# Rails - collection_select for SELECT - similar func for RADIO BUTTONs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use collection_select for Select form elements. Does Rails have a similar method for Radio Buttons? Or do you need to use X number for from tags to render a set of radio buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this within your view:

```
<% ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'].each do |option| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag 'tag_name', option %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously, substitute `['option1', 'option2', 'option3']` with any array that comes from a more reasonable place than hard-coded in the view :)

If you're using a `form_for`, use `f.radio_button` instead of `radio_button_tag`.